# Auto Generate two new ID column based on other column Values in PostGreSQL database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dynamically-generated

In my database table i have a table name Household member where the column are

> Upzila, union , ward, village , para family_head_name , member_name ,
> relation_with_family_head, age , maritial_status.

I want to generate a new table with same structure but with new auto-generate column the column name will be **HH_ID** , **Member_id** .Below i will provide simple dataset with the new example column of hh_id and hh_membe_id.
For example the Upazila is Cox Bazar Sadar so i will assume the code is 1 and the union is jhiwanja so jhionja code is 03 then if ward is number 1 and village is Boro chara so code is 01 and the para name is asroyon prokolo that code is 02 so  the hh_id will be [image] and the member id will be incremental for example if the house hold contain 3 people so for the first member id (hh_member_id) will be [image] then second member id will be [image].
I have tried so many approch  but i faild to generate that id . last time i have tried to generate the id using excel manually but i faild . so would be the best solution to do that in postgreSQL database .
Simple dataset link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X33Zh2Yq_9Hz64VbW_u3lRi61-pKfQ5HozkylUsRVMU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The only way I see this happening is with a ```ON INSERT/UPDATE``` trigger function that contains the logic necessary to build the ```hh_id``` first. Then it would need to find count of existing members belonging to household and create ```hh_member_id``` with incremented member number.

Comment: but how can i set the number for upazila  because its not a only one or two village or union

Comment: I don't know what Upzila is? Regardless of what it is there needs to be some business logic that predetermines how codes/numbers are assigned  to each attribute you wish to track.

Comment: where these Codes of all upzila, village etc. are stored? in same table or different

Comment: Right now thats not set i will set in another table.